# How to show that two vectors are orthogonal in an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb F$ and  $u$,$v$ ∈ $V$ and
$\|u\| ≤ \|u + av\|$
for all $a$ ∈ $\mathbb{F}$.Then I want to show that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal.I want to prove it geometrically.Somebody please give me some hint.

Comment: It might be good to specify that $V$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb F$ (where $\mathbb F$ is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) and that $\| \cdot \|$ is the norm induced by the inner product.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric arguments fall apart somewhat over $\Bbb C$
$$
\|u + av\|^2 = 
\langle u + av, u + av\rangle = 
\|u\|^2 + |a|^2\|v\|^2 + 2 \text{Re}(a\langle u,v \rangle)
$$
If we are only talking about $\Bbb R$, this is now a quadratic function on $a$.

Otherwise, we can just try setting $a = -\frac{\overline{\langle u,v \rangle}}{\|v\|}$.  This gives us
$$
\|u + av\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + |\langle u,v\rangle|^2 - 2|\langle u,v\rangle|^2 = 
\|u\|^2 - |\langle u,v\rangle|^2
$$
So, your inequality implies
$$
\|u\| \leq \|u\|^2 - |\langle u,v\rangle|^2
$$
the conclusion follows.

Comment: yes I know this proof.I want to prove it geometrically i.e can i show that $u$ and $v$ are perpendicular using the given inequality?

Comment: See my edit, perhaps this clarifies what I mean. If this is not your looking for, I'm not sure what kind of proof would qualify as "geometric".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful visualization (though not quite a rigorous proof) in the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$:

Let $u$ be the black vector and $v$ be the blue vector.

Then for $a > 0$, $u + av$ lies on the green line, while for $b < 0$, $u+ bv$ lies on the red line.

You can see that everything on the green line lies outside the black arc i.e. $$\forall a > 0: \|u\| \leq \|u+av \|$$ but some points on the red line lie inside the black arc i.e. $$\exists b<0 : \|u\| > \|u+bv \|$$

[image]

In general, this will always be the case unless both of the red and green lines are tangent to the circle, which is the same as saying $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal.

For a rigorous proof, you'll probably have to resort to something like Omnomnomnom's answer, although you could still use the picture to guide you.